# How to write a program, which gets two numbers (N and K) and generates 5-letter strings

Tags: c#

I need help with the following problem, I can't understand it right. Could you please give me an advice how to start and what exactly to do. Thank you in advance.

This is the problem and its description

> Write a program, which gets two numbers (`N` and `K`) and generates 5-letter strings ordered alphabetically, which represent all possible combinations consisting of the following five symbols:
>
> - Symbol 1: digit from 1 to `N`
> - Symbol 2: digit from 1 to `N`
> - Symbol 3: letter (a-z), which is amongst the first `K` letters of the alphabet
> - Symbol 4: letter (a-z), which is amongst the first `K` letters of the alphabet
> - Symbol 5: digit from 1 to `N`, larger than the first two digits

Here I will paste the inputs and outputs

- First input: `2 4`

  Output: 11aa2 11ab2 11ac2 11ad2 11ba2 11bb2 11bc2 11bd2 11ca2 11cb2 11cc2 11cd2 11da2 11db2 11dc2 11dd2
- Second input: `3 1`

  Output: 11aa2 11aa3 12aa3 21aa3 22aa3
- Third input: `3 2`

  Output: 11aa2 11aa3 11ab2 11ab3 11ba2 11ba3 11bb2 11bb3 12aa3 12ab3 12ba3 12bb3 21aa3 21ab3 21ba3 21bb3 22aa3 22ab3 22ba3 22bb3

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Yes and its in one book and its the hardest I got so i need assistance .

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you stuck on something specific?

Comment: The problem is that i can't understand the description

Comment: Which part of the description more specifically?

Comment: The explanation after it and it is hard to imagin how to make it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208365/discussion-between-olian04-and-draksbg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my answer :)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    function(2, 4);
}
public static void function(int n, int k)
{
    for (int i1 = 1; i1 <= n; i1++)
    {         
        for (int i2 = 1; i2 <= n; i2++)
        {
            for (int i3 = 1; i3 <= k; i3++)
            {
                for (int i4 = 1; i4 <= k; i4++)
                {
                    for (int i5 = 1; i5 <= n; i5++)
                    {
                        if (i5 > i1 && i5 > i2)
                        Console.Write($"{i1}{i2}{Convert.ToChar(96 + i3)}{Convert.ToChar(96 + i4)}{i5},");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can get answer of

```
11aa2,11ab2,11ac2,11ad2,11ba2,11bb2,11bc2,11bd2,11ca2,11cb2,11cc2,11cd2,11da2,11db2,11dc2,11dd2
```

From `function(2, 4);` as you said.
Please answer :)
I put `96+` inside of `Convert.ToChar()` because `a` starts from 97

Comment: how can it be made in recursion

Comment: Because, if you read the question, the question itself has few conditions. We have two conditions, ```(i1, i2, i5 is number, i3,i4 is character)```, ```(i5 > i1&i2)```.  For the first condition, I made a ```int n``` and ```int k``` and put them into the ```for(;;)```. For the second condition, I put ```if (i5 > i1 && i5 > i2)```. I put the if sentence to Write on the console if the condition meets. Is this enough to be an answer?